# nodeMCU - 2 loops at a time - one continuously and second every 10 seconds

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, programming, nodemcu

i have nodeMCU v3(esp8266) so i need to make 2 checks 
1 check is the pin D1 which needs to be done continuously  and another check is web link check every 10 seconds, 
problem is coz when i put delay then it stops the first check

```
void loop() {

 if (digitalRead(pinD1)==1){
       digitalWrite(pinD0, HIGH);
       delay(20000);  
 }else{
       digitalWrite(pinD0, LOW);
 }

      loop2();  

}



void loop2(){
   if (json1=="ON"){
    digitalWrite(pinD0, HIGH);
      delay(20000);  
}else{
     digitalWrite(pinD0, LOW);
               delay(10000);  

  }
}
```

Comment: `loop2()`  is not a loop, it is a subroutine or a function .... why don't  you give it a descriptive name like `updateD0()`?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `delay`, use `millis()` and a variable to check if the some time has expired

```
void loop()
{
    static int check = 0;
    int now = millis();
    if (now >= check) {
        if (digitalRead(pinD1)==1){
            digitalWrite(pinD0, HIGH);
            check = now + 20000;  
        } else {
            digitalWrite(pinD0, LOW);
            check = now;
        }
    }
    loop2();  
}

void loop2()
{
    static int check = 0;
    int now = millis();
    if (now >= check) {
        if (json1=="ON"){
            digitalWrite(pinD0, HIGH);
        } else {
            digitalWrite(pinD0, LOW);
        }
        check = now + 20000;
    }
}
```